# Paycharm Not Working - Can't open a file / No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation, kite

Paycharm is not working even after the installation of the following resources

1. Python, latest version 3.11
2. Selenium, latest version 4.82
3. Paycharm, latest version PyCharm community edition 2022.3.3

Kite Setup was installed but it did not integrate with Paycharm as they ended there their support so installed another one Named as

AIXCoder installed and integrated with Paycharm.

Tried to check and test everything as new path created and this new path also added in environment variable. Then I added the Chrome driver and give path as well.

When I tried to run the Paycharm it gives me following error

[image]

I tried to check that Python is working separately and it was working same as Selenium and other stuff but when error is still exists